# What is the range of a 2dB usb wifi dongle?

Tags: power, usb, rf, wifi

For a home robotics project I need to connect my laptop to my robot's Raspberry Pi using wifi. For this to work I want to buy a simple usb wifi adapter to plug into my Raspi. I will need a range of about 100Meters.

After some searching around I read some things about RF power. For example, [this USB-Wifi adapter](http://dx.com/p/mini-portable-usb-802-11b-g-n-300mbps-wifi-wireless-network-adapter-black-103696) has 2dBmW RF power. My question is: what kind of range can I expect from 2dBmW (assuming an open field without obstructions)? And what kind of range can I expect from my built in laptop wifi?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Could somebody maybe explain why my question is downvoted? I'm really curious to what kind of range I could expect, and since I can't find the answer anywhere I wouldn't understand why this would be a stupid question.

Comment: 2dB means nothing without a reference and the usual way of referencing is to "attach" the letter "m" to it i.e. 2dBm. Now this is a usable number because it means 2dB more signal than 1mW. Just saying 2dB could mean anything and I suspect, that buying something from people who say 2dB will be risky. It's like saying you have 1Mbit internet speed when in fact you mean 1Mbit per second.

Comment: I don't see dBm anywhere but I do see a lot of dBi.. My question remains. What range can I expect from a "normal" USB-Wifi adapter?

Comment: dBi is a relative measurement of an antenna's gain compared to an isotropic antenna. This does not apply to this module. Going back to what I said - I cannot tell how much power is being transmitted by the unit therefore it is impossible to say what its range is under any or perfect conditions.

Comment: Even with the still missing power level, this could not be answered without knowledge of receiver sensitivity, antenna gain and orientation, and interference environment.  As a guess though, its unlikely to work, at least not reliably, though in a quiet environment with directional antennas, perhaps.  You might want to look at something like the long range version of zigbee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you can do is to read what they provide you, so either you find some dongle like this:

http://dx.com/p/sl-1506n-mini-ieee802-11b-g-n-150mbps-usb-2-0-wi-fi-wireless-network-adapter-w-antenna-black-167596

where the ranges are stated, or you can (better) rely on some people experiences (finding some real tests of range), as the provided ranges are rarely true or useful. You have to remember that power of wireless power is not the only factor which decides upon it's range, but antenna size also matters (if not even more in quite a few devices).

Also, maximum legal power for unlicensed use is mostly 150mW, but that might vary between countries.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as was already pointed out there is a mistake in the spec: "RF power: 2 dB". This statement does not make sense. If they are talking about power, the proper unit is either dBm (referenced to a mW) or dBW (referenced to W). 
Since the antenna they are using is a dipole (gain of about 2 dBi) it is quite possible they mean gain, which is a measure of how RF power is focused (a perfect antenna radiating uniformly in every direction would have a gain of 0 dBi). 
In free space the relationship between transmit and receive power is governed by Friis equation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation
The other parameter you would need to know to answer your question is receiver sensitivity (minimum signal power in dBm, e.g. -90 dBm). That number also depends on a data rate (you can get away with lower receive power at lower data rates).